# How to manually create Friendly URLs? (PHP)

Tags: php, url, html

How to manually create Friendly URLs? (PHP)
So I have created simple php file which echos requested string. Now it has form `echo.php?string=bla+bla+bla&font=times`
I want to see it like `echo/bla+bla+bla/times` How to do such thing (not using external libs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the 404 handler idea, with a very simple RewriteRule you can easily move the URL rewriting management to PHP, which might be easier for you:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . rewrite.php [L]
```

In `rewrite.php` you have an array of RegEx URL patterns. These can be used to match the current URL (use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) and hand over parts of the URL to a real file. The parameters can then just be put into the `$_GET` array and the correct file can be included.

As an example, the array could look like this:

```
$rules = array(
    array(
        'articles/view/([0-9]+)',
        'articles.php?id=$1'
    ),
    array(
        'articles/delete/([0-9]+)',
        'articles.php?id=$1&action=delete'
    ),
);
```

Comment: I know I'm a bit late, but the reason I'm not a fan of this style is that it seems like the exact same thing as the `mod_rewrite` syntax, but reimplemented in PHP. It actually seems like *more* work, rebuilding the wheel. Of course, there are times when a PHP router is appropriate, like an MVC style where we're routing to controller actions rather than single PHP files. For this, though, stick to `mod_rewrite`, which does the exact same thing.

Comment: This is especially useful, though, if you're creating software that is supposed to work regardless of the server system you use. Of course you still have to add the mod_rewrite rules mentioned above, but these are much easier to replicate on other servers (e.g. lighttpd) than the full list of routes. May be minor, but I find it useful. And, of course, you can create a more advanced system than this (mod_rewrite-like) one.

Answer (score 5):

This is typically done with the `mod_rewrite` Apache extension. In the .htaccess file, you would put something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^echo/(.+?)/(.+)$ echo.php?string=$1&font=$2 [L]
```

The first line activates `mod_rewrite`. The second sets up a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to route requests matching that pattern to the PHP file you want.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use the [Rewrite engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) which is the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in apache server.

Answer (score 2):

To turn `echo.php` into `echo` you'll need to use a rewriting facility for your web server.  If you're running Apache, [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is king.

For the rest of it, you just need to parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` using a [regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).  You can use mod_rewrite to do this part also, but in case that's not an option, it can be done in straight PHP.

Comment: Problem is, "the rest" isn't quite that easy. You do have to use mod_rewrite or something similar on different servers than Apache to be able to use PHP to do the rewriting (well, except if you're talking about something along the lines of `index.php/article/id/123`, which is regarded as ugly by many ;)

Comment: @Franz What I meant was, if mod_rewrite isn't an option, you can accept `echo.php/bla+bla+bla/times` and parse it using PHP only.  Or you can use the hybrid solution: mod_rewrite to rewrite `echo/anything` to `echo.php/anything` and then use the PHP-based URL parsing.  Or you can use mod_rewrite exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the .htaccess file that is generated in a new Zend Framework project. You can use it without the rest of the framework or use it as an example for your own URL-rewriting method.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to rewriting the URL through mod_rewrite, just set a php file to be the 404 error handler. That file can analyze the URL and determine how it should be processed.

```
 $path_parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
 echo $path_parts[0]. ', '.$path_parts[1].' font';
```

For performance reasons, you wouldn't want to configure apache to not send certain file types (i.e. gif, jpg, png, etc) to PHP for handling.

While there are a number of different things you can do, as mentioned in the responses, you can't do it without adjusting configurations in the web server.

Comment: Don't forget to send the correct header (`HTTP 200`), though. As far as I remember, some servers automatically send the `404` header when using a 404 error handler unless you overwrite it.